# A method to search Id inside a matrix -Trouble with output

Tags: c#, matrix, methods, output

I am new at programming and I am trying to create a method that allows me search Id  inside a [10,4] matrix, however I don't get how to do it without using nested fors and also if and else statement. The problem is related to output, I know the structure isn't correct, but since I don't what else can be done I am trying make it as it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace menu
{
    class Program
    {
        enum header { id, name, surname, addres };

        public static int id = 1;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[,] matrix = new string[10, 4];

            insertStudent(matrix);
            idSearch(matrix);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        static int generateId()
        {
            return id++;
        }

        static void insertStudent(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int n = generateId();
            matrix[n - 1, 0] = Convert.ToString(n);

            for (int i = 1; i < matrix.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Insert {Enum.GetName(typeof(header), i)}");
                    matrix[n - 1, i] = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix[n - 1, i]));

            }
        }

            static void idSearch(string[,] matrix)

        {
            int idChosen=0;
            Console.WriteLine($"Insert ID you want to visualize:");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out idChosen);
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {


                    if (matrix[i, 0] == Convert.ToString(idChosen))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(matrix[i, j]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The chosen ID does not exist");
                    }

                }

            }
        }









    }

}
```

Comment: `The problem is related to output` so what's the problem?

Comment: The else statement is executed everytime the nested for is being executed

Comment: Did you debug it and make sure the id does exist in the array?

Comment: Id does exit the problem is that it is shown the if stament when exists and the rest of the loops the else statment

Answer (score 1):

Right now you printing "The chosen ID does not exist" every time you check an index in your matrix. You want to move that statement to outside of your loop after you've already checked every index. Right now that check is really saying that your ID is not in that specific cell. I've altered your code slightly to reflect this. I also fixed your check to be on `matrix[i,j]` instead of `matrix[i,0]`

Also using a nested `for` loop is OK to use. I don't believe C# has any built in helper methods for searching multidimensional arrays.

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (matrix[i, j] == Convert.ToString(idChosen))
                {
                    //note that this will print your id
                    Console.WriteLine(matrix[i, j]);
                    //this would print where it found it
                    Console.WriteLine("Found at [" + i + "," + j + "]");
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }

if (!found)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The chosen ID does not exist");
}
```