# C# method to check if ID exists and after display Data Inserted

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a CRUD menu that allows me to insert data at an array and also search it by id.

However I'm trying to create a method that allow to check if id exists and after to display the output.

The problem is that the method isn't correct enough for me to display it across other methods, and also at a switch statement. The problem is it repeats two times in row what is the Id you want to check.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace menu
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int id = 1;
        enum dataInsert { ID, NAME, SURNAME, ADDRES };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[,] matrix = new string[10, 4];

            insertData(matrix);
            searchId(matrix);     
            visualizeByid(matrix);
        }

        static int generateId()
        {
            return id++;
        }

        static void insertData(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int n = generateId();

            for (int j = 1; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                matrix[n - 1, 0] = Convert.ToString(n);
                Console.Write($"Insert {Enum.GetName(typeof(dataInsert), j)}: ");
                matrix[n - 1, j] = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        static int searchId(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int choosenId, index = -1;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Insert Id to visualize: ");

            } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choosenId));

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(choosenId) == matrix[i, 0])
                {
                    index = i;
                }
            }

            return index;
        }

        static void visualizeByid(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int pos = searchId(matrix);

            for (int i = pos; i < pos + 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest going for an Dictionary, that way you can't add ID's twice. If you try, you will get an error which you could catch and return to the user. Or use LinQ to check if array `.contains` the item you'd like to add.

Comment: You can start removing the call to _searchId_ inside the _visualizeByid_ and instead pass the return value from the call _searchId_ inside the main method. However this code doesn't allow inserting more than one element in your _matrix_

Comment: Lol the way you describe this makes me think you and [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677285/a-method-to-search-id-inside-a-matrix-trouble-with-output) are working on the exact same assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason "Insert Id to visualize: " is displayed twice is because your program is calling `static int searchId(string[,] matrix)` twice in a row:

In `Main`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[,] matrix = new string[10, 4];

            insertData(matrix);
            searchId(matrix); //Here    
            visualizeByid(matrix);  //Called immediately after
        }
```

And `visualizeByid`

```
static void visualizeByid(string[,] matrix)
    {
        int pos = searchId(matrix); //Here
        ...
    }
```

You should be able to get your expected result by removing the call to searchId from `Main`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, it looks like you have an array of objects.  Even if those are simply a name and id.

```
public class Obj
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have an array, although you could also use a list.

```
List<Obj> Objects = new List<Obj>();
```

To check the list/array by Id you can simply use Linq

```
if (Objects.Where(o => o.Id == IdToCheck).Count() == 0)
{
  //Insert new object
  Objects.Add(NewObject);
}
```